# java.io.FileNotFoundException: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/24093/photo for old photos only

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap

I'm getting my contacts image uris from my phone contacts list.

However when i try convert the image uri to bitmap i get an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/24093/photo
```

It has something to do with old photos on my device, as if i take a new photo it is shown OK.

so maybe the old photos are too big or not OK, but the exception says `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

How can i verify it's a access rights issue?

```
      final Bitmap bitmap;
      try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ab.getContentResolver(), tryUri);
        ab.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // make sure the tag is still the one we set at the beginning of this function
            if (toSet.getTag() == urlStr) {
              toSet.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        String a = "1";
      } catch (IOException e) {
        String a = "1";
      } catch (Exception e) {
        String a = "1";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities: 1) The uri you're using is not good anymore.  You can repull a new one using ContactsContract.
2) The contact you're pulling, 24093, may no longer exist or was merged into another contact.  Therefore there is no primary contact photo anymore.

Try this using the ContactsContract instead of getBitmap.  You'll end up with a null if the photo doesn't exist instead of a FileNotFound error:

```
private void showPic(String photoUri) {
    Bitmap[] array = new Bitmap[2];
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(photoUri),
            new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (data != null) {
                array[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    if (array[0] != null) {toSet.setImageBitmap(array[0]);}
}
```